# Running Python script in PHP:

Tags: php, python

I make Relay-Website-with-Raspberry now python application is work but on php is no work 
this php screp,

```
<?php

    $output = shell_exec('sudo python 1on.py 2>&1');

    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

    header("Location: ../index.php");

    exit;

?>
```

Comment: <?php
$output = shell_exec('sudo python 1on.py 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
header("Location: ../index.php");
exit;
?>

Comment: Try using the full path name for the python script.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a right procedure to run a python script, Instead running python script in sudo mode give your file permission to www-data

```
chgrp www-data /path/to/python-script.py
```

put first line in your python script: #!/usr/bin/env python so the script knows which program to open it with..

Make your script executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/python-script.py
```

then try running the script

```
<?php

    $output = shell_exec("/path/to/python-script.py");

    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

    header("Location: ../index.php");

    exit;

?>
```

Comment: I try but cannot  ,pi@raspberrypi:~ $ chgrp www-data /var/www/html/py/to/1on.py
chgrp: cannot access '/var/www/html/py/to/1on.py': No such file or directory

Comment: @MalikAlrushaidi are you sure about the file path, to me, it seems like you have entered an invalid path.